# Optimization over a complex optimization variable

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I found a highly cited IEEE paper that optimizes over a complex optimization variable. However, they are only dealing with the magnitude of the this complex random variable multiplied by other complex constant in their problem. But, I don't understand how to show a complex problem to be convex? and how to solve it? Can I simply solve it using the lagrangian duality? I have a similar problem as follows,

$ \underset{x}{\text{Maximize}} \; \;   |b^* x|$

S.T.

$ x^* x \leq 1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$     %that's a magnitude square constraint on x

$|a^* \; x|    = 0 $

where x is a $M \times 1$ complex optimization variable,
$b$ is $M \times 1$ complex constant vector, $a$ is $M \times 1$ complex constant vector as well.

the IEEE Paper with similar formulation where they highlighted that the problem is convex, problem 6 in: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4557080

Your help is very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not tell us what the name of this mysterious highly cited IEEE paper is?

Comment: sure, please refer to problem 6 in : http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4557080

Comment: One approach is to write $x = x_1 +i x_2$, and rephrase the problem in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$ (so now all the optimization variables are real).

Comment: Thank you. I tried the rephrasing into real optimization variables approach but I could not prove that the problem is convex.